# Chain Reaction with Arrays and Distance

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, distance

I want to make a program in which mines will appear on the screen after a user inputs the number of mines. Then, the user will click on one mine and set off a chain reaction that explodes the nearest two mines.

So far, my code can prompt the user for the number of mines, and then display them. The mines are buttons in which, when clicked, will be removed and an explosion will appear.

However, I am stuck with how I can handle the chain reaction. I am relatively new to coding in AS3 and therefore am stumped with no clue on how to approach this part of my program.

Code:

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;
import flash.events.*;

public class Minefield extends MovieClip
{

    var integer:int;
    var iField:TextField = new TextField();
    var button:iButton = new iButton();
    var i:int;
    var mines:Array = new Array();

    public function Minefield()
    {

        var explosion:iExplosion = new iExplosion();

        iField.type = "input";
        iField.height = 18;
        iField.x = 460;
        iField.y = 275;
        iField.border = true;
        iField.restrict = "0-9";
        iField.maxChars = 2;
        stage.focus = iField;
        addChild(iField);
        addChild(button);
        button.x = 450;
        button.y = 175;
        button.buttonMode = true;
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, UponClick);


    }

    function AddMines()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < integer; i++)
        {
            CreatorOfMine();
            mines[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, UponMineClick)
            mines[i].buttonMode = true;
        }
    }

    function CreatorOfMine()
    {

        mines[i] = new Mine();
        MineLocation()
    }

    function MineLocation()
    {
        mines[i].x = Math.round(Math.random() * 925);
        mines[i].y = Math.round(Math.random() * 525);
        mines[i].rotation = Math.random() * 360;
        addChild(mines[i]);

    }

    function UponClick(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        integer = int(iField.text);
        RemoverOfChildren();

    }

    function RemoverOfChildren()
    {
        removeChild(button);
        removeChild(iField);
        AddMines();
    }

    function UponMineClick(event:MouseEvent){
        var mineObject:Mine = Mine(event.currentTarget)
        var expl:iExplosion = new iExplosion() 
        expl.x = mineObject.x
        expl.y = mineObject.y
        expl.rotation = mineObject.rotation
        addChild(expl)
        removeChild(mineObject)

    }
    }
}
}
```

Information you may need/want:

Stage size is 1024 x 600 (px)

Size of mine(s) is 40 x 40 (px)

Size of explosion is 40 x 40 (px)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good case for recursion. Pseudo-code:

```
Function ExplodeMine(mine) {
    mine.boooooooooom()
    nearest = findNearestUnexplodedMines()
    foreach(nextMine in nearest) {
        ExplodMine(nextMine);
    }
}
```

Just start ExplodeMine on the first mine that is clicked.

Comment: `findNearestUnexplodedMines()`

This sounds like it is hard to do. How do I make the program determine the two closest mines? Should I make another array and insert the distances, sort them and take the first two?

Edit: Shift+Enter

Comment: This depends on your requirements. If you have a small distance to search next to each mine (presumably mines only explode mines which are near?) Then you can just write a rudimentary local check on your grid around the mine (for(x =... for(y =... etc). You can make this slightly more optimal by keeping track of which nodes have been checked (though in this case the operation to check if a node has been touched is only going to be marginally cheaper than working out if it has a mine in it anyway). If you want to delve deeper, then look at pathfinding (which will give distance). I'm a fan of A*

Comment: [Okay...(link)](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/4d/4d9f5501ec186b510e0b95128ad9ab421a4978698088861976f1f7505ea16868.jpg)

Forgive my ignorance, but I couldn't quite understand what you mean. Can you please explain with, uhm, simpler vocabulary? =D